# Why do images appear at incorrect positions in my QGraphicsView-derived class?

Tags: c++, image, qt, view

I have created an override of QGraphicsView for displaying images inside a QMdiSubWindow in my application. Later I plan to add support for other floating shapes on top of that so a QLabel just wasn't enough. Here's the basic layout of the class:

```
class ImageView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    ImageView(QWidget *parent);
    ~ImageView();

    bool clean() const
    {
        return _clean;
    }

    void showImage(const QString &path);

private:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

    bool _clean;
    QGraphicsScene *_scene;
    QPixmap _viewPixmap;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *_viewPixmapItem;
};
```

I want to avoid allocating a QPixmap element every time I load a new image, so I just keep one in the class, and also create a pixmap graphics item in the constructor like this:

```
ImageView::ImageView(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent), _clean(true)
{
    _scene = new QGraphicsScene(this); 
    _scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::lightGray);
    _viewPixmapItem = _scene->addPixmap(_viewPixmap);
    setScene(_scene);
}
```

Later when someone clicks on an image in the app, I call (from the main gui class) the showImage function:

```
void ImageView::showImage(const QString &path)
{
    _clean = false;
    _viewPixmap.load(path);
    _viewPixmapItem->setPixmap(_viewPixmap);
}
```

My problem is that the first time I use showImage(), the image is not placed at the top left corner in the view, but rather somewhere near the middle, with most of it outside the view and yet no scrollbar is visible. The next time I try to show an image, I get a resize event after the call to showImage(), the image is displayed correctly, and all subsequent displays are okay; the image is aligned with the top-left corner of the view, and scrollbars are visible to reflect that the image is too large for the view (I plan to add zoom capability later). I read the docs over and over but just got more confused, can you please give me a hint of what I am missing? Thanks.

**EDIT:** [Here's](http://grafit.mchtr.pw.edu.pl/~szczedar/1.png) how the image looks at the first call to showImage, and [here](http://grafit.mchtr.pw.edu.pl/~szczedar/2.png) is how it looks on the subsequent ones, which is what I want. You can see that the image view widget is placed in a MDI-style sub window within a QMdiArea.

**EDIT2:** The application writes information to a log file, here's the part where I try to show the first three images:

> Activated image in project list, name: obiekt_blisko-0000_0.bmp
>     ViewMdiSubWindow::prefit: Pre-fitting, new size: 516x352
>     MDI window size: 516x352
>     Child QWidget window size: 628x477
>     ImageView::resizeEvent: Received resize event, old size was: -1x-1, new size: 500x313
>     ImageView::showImage: Showing image: D:\praca\dane\pomiar3d_3\obiekt_blisko_L\obiekt_blisko-0000_0.bmp
>     View size after setting new pixmap: 502x315
>     Item position (parent coords): 0,0

(After this, the image is displayed incorrectly)

> Activated image in project list, name: obiekt_blisko-0001_0.bmp
>     MDI window size: 516x352
>     Child QWidget window size: 502x315
>     ImageView::showImage: Showing image: D:\praca\dane\pomiar3d_3\obiekt_blisko_L\obiekt_blisko-0001_0.bmp
>     View size after setting new pixmap: 502x315
>     Item position (parent coords): 0,0
>   ImageView::resizeEvent: Received resize event, old size was: 500x313, new size: 483x296

(Now the image is OK)

> Activated image in project list, name: obiekt_blisko-0002_0.bmp
>     MDI window size: 516x352
>     Child QWidget window size: 502x315
>     ImageView::showImage: Showing image: D:\praca\dane\pomiar3d_3\obiekt_blisko_L\obiekt_blisko-0002_0.bmp
>     View size after setting new pixmap: 502x315
>     Item position (parent coords): 0,0

(This and the next events are identical and the images are OK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the image is showing with its top-left corner at the center of the view is because your scene has a `sceneRect` of (0,0,0,0) and `QGraphicsView` shows the scene centered by default.

Set [`seneRect`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) to a fix rect will probably solve your problem. Calling [`centerOn`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn) after the image change will also help.

Comment: Also, I don't see the need to sub-class QGraphicsView. All you want can be done outside of QGraphicsView. But I don't know your other needs.

Comment: That was exactly it! Now I call setSceneRect(0, 0, _viewPixmap.width(), _viewPixmap.height()) after pointing the pixmap item to the new image and I get exactly what I want. :) I don't want the image to auto center, but rather to keep the scroll position between image changes, so I'll avoid centerOn. But I need to subclass QGraphicsView because I plan to add support for other user-defined, draggable shapes floating above the images later. Anyway, thanks, I was getting desperate. :)

Comment: Oddly enough, before I added the call to setSceneRect(), but tried to access its dimensions for debug logging to see what values it has, the image was OK. It's as if accessing the scene rectangle dimensions makes it update itself to reflect the image.

Comment: The "user-defined, draggable shapes" sound like a perfect case for custom QGrahpicsItems. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't _viewPixmapItem->setPos(0, 0) work in showImage? As you describe it, it's just in the wrong postion. Maybe centered with the initial zero size.

Comment: That would be my guess too, and I tried it but it didn't help. Also, the problem is not just the position, it's also the scrollbars not showing which seems to mean the view has more of an issue with the image than just it's position. :(